# Inserting and extracting subclasses from a linked list made for a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, linked-list

I have made a generic linked list

```
Container<String, Person>
```

that holds Person objects. I need to fill this list with objects of the two subclasses called respectively Owners and Mechanics. This part is currently going ok (I'm creating the owner and mechanics objects as the respective subclasses they belong to and use my insert function to put them in the list), but when I try to extract owners or mechanics using the following method:

```
Owner o = container.get("John");
```

I get the following error:

```
error: "incompatible types
        Owner o = container.get("John");                                  ^
         required: Eier
  found:    Person
```

How can I circumvent/solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the compiler doesn't know that `"John"` is an `Owner`.
You can cast:

```
Owner o = (Owner)container.get("John");
```

or check if it is an `Owner` before casting to avoid avoidable exception, using `instanceof`.

```
Person p = container.get("John");
if (p instanceof Owner){
    Owner o = (Owner) p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how happy I am right now! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) you made me happy too :D

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is right: all it knows about the object is that it's a `Person`, not an `Owner`. If you know for sure that `"John"` is an `Owner`, add an explicit cast.

This may not be the most elegant way to solve the problem, because the cast will fail if `"John"` is not an `Owner`. When you run into the need to "downcast" to subclass, you should evaluate your decision to put `Owner`s and `Mechanic`s into the same container: perhaps your code would be better off if the containers for the two subclasses were separate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to typecast it

```
Owner o = (Owner)container.get("John");
```

If its Mechanics then you need to do

```
Mechanics m = (Mechanics) container.get("John");
```

So its better to do it this way

```
for(Person p : container)  
{  
  if (p instance of Owner)  
     Owner o = (Owner) p;  
  else  
     Mechanics m = (Mechanics) p;  
}
```